# REST or JMS or anything else?

Tags: java

Got a situation here, I have a system where user submits a request to fetch data from some third party APIs. When user submits the request, the form parameters got stored in database and a java service is running continuously to poll the database for new sessions and do further processing.

My questions are:

1. Is it a good approach to have a infinite running JAVA service to poll the database? or
2. Should I use REST API to invoke the java service when use submits a request? or
3. Is it a good approach to have a JMS based system in which the continuously running service will poll the queue instead of Database? or
4. Please suggest any other efficient way to do it.

Comment: If it works and the latency is okay, then there is nothing wrong with having a message queue in the database. A dedicated system may be better at it, but it also means more moving parts for you to look after. So check if you have performance/cost/scalability issues with your current setup first.

Comment: In the current setup, the database hits can be considered more expensive. So I thought of going for some other option to achieve this. About latency, it is ok with smaller data set, going forward doing so many database hits would definitely degrade the performance.